# how to access xml attributes in python

Tags: python, xml

My XML file sample is given below and I want to access text "The bread is top notch as well" and category "food".

```
<sentences>
     <sentence id="32897564#894393#2">
         <text>The bread is top notch as well.</text>
         <aspectTerms>
             <aspectTerm term="bread" polarity="positive"  from="4" to="9"/>
         </aspectTerms>
         <aspectCategories>
             <aspectCategory category="food" polarity="positive" />
         </aspectCategories>
     </sentence>
```

my code is

```
 test_text_file=open('Restaurants_Test_Gold.txt', 'rt')
 test_text_file1=test_text_file.read()
 root = ET.fromstring(test_text_file1)
 for page in list(root):
     text = page.find('text').text
     Category = page.find('aspectCategory')
     print ('sentence: %s; category: %s' % (text,Category))
 test_text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depending on how complicated your XML format is. The easiest way is to access the path directly.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print(root.find('.//text').text)
print(root.find('.//aspectCategory').attrib['category'])
```

But if there are similar tags, you might want to use longer path like `.//aspectCategories/aspectCategory` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code solving your problem

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
filenamepath = os.path.join(basedir, 'Restaurants_Test_Gold.txt')

test_text_file = open(filenamepath, 'r')
file_contents = test_text_file.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(file_contents)

for sentence in list(tree):
    sentence_items = list(sentence.iter())
    # remove first element because it's the sentence element [<sentence>] itself
    sentence_items = sentence_items[1:]
    for item in sentence_items:
        if item.tag == 'text':
            print(item.text)
        elif item.tag == 'aspectCategories':
            category = item.find('aspectCategory')
            print(category.attrib.get('category'))

test_text_file.close()
```

Hope it helps